# Using iOS Worklight Library in Unit Tests

Tags: ios, unit-testing, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm attempting to use the Worklight iOS native Client library in some unit tests.  I find that the tests crash on the following assertion:

```
 XCTAssertNotNil([WLClient sharedInstance], @"wlclient shouldn't be nil");
```

With the following stacktrace:

```
sharedTests.m:65: error: -[sharedTests testLogin] : (([WLClient sharedInstance]) != nil) failed: throwing "-[__NSDate getTime]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2b5df90" - wlclient shouldn't be nil
2014-07-28 12:47:07.520 xctest[6456:303] -[__NSDate getTime]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2953a90
<unknown>:0: error: -[sharedTests testLogin] : -[__NSDate getTime]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2953a90
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00b251e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x007988e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00bc2243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00b1550b ___forwarding___ + 1019
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00b150ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
5   sharedTests                         0x066e1e55 +[System currentTimeMillis] + 85
6   sharedTests                         0x066e672e -[DeviceContextPiggybacker init:] + 318
7   sharedTests                         0x066eb1ff -[DeviceImpl init:::::] + 927
8   sharedTests                         0x06718465 -[IOSWLDevice init] + 549
9   sharedTests                         0x06729907 -[WLClient init] + 951
10  sharedTests                         0x06729358 +[WLClient sharedInstance] + 120
```

Wondering if there's any special setup/teardown that the worklight library requires, outside of importing the requisite worklight.plist file and Cookies.mom into the unit tests.

It’s just a unit test in iOS with no dependencies besides worklight.  So - the steps are

1: set up a unit test

2: include worklight library

3: assert that the shared worklight client isn’t nil on initialization.

Comment: Please edit the question with steps to reproduce or even better, a demo native project containing everything required to see this error.

Comment: It’s just a unit test in iOS with no dependencies besides worklight.  So - the steps are 


1: set up a unit test 


2: include worklight library 


3: assert that the shared worklight client isn’t nil on initialization.

Comment: I understand. But to make sure, I'd appreciate a demo project from you so we could debug what you see and not what we think you'll see. Please upload a demo projext to Dropbox.

Comment: Here you go: http://cl.ly/3L1P2Q1l1J0z - I'm specifically concerned about the failing unit test for this project.

Comment: Many thanks. If no one else will get to this first, I will take a look at this at the beginning of the work day (tomorrow...).

Answer (score 0):

I've tried running the [Xcode project you've provided](http://cl.ly/3L1P2Q1l1J0z), but it failed on other errors so I've done the following and in my case it passed successfully.

The project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/c03mndpky0r8c10/UnitTestProject.zip

1. Created a new Single View Application in Xcode
2. Followed the instructions provided [in the Hello World in Native iOS training module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/02_02_Creating_your_first_Native_iOS_Worklight_application.pdf).
   This includes adding the:

   - WorklightAPI folder
   - Required frameworks
   - -ObjC flag
   - etc... (see the *guide*)
3. Opened the *Tests.m file and add the following to the `testExample` function:

   `XCTAssertNotNil([WLClient sharedInstance], @"wlclient shouldn't be nil");`
4. Selected Product > Test

The end result (note the green check marks):
[image]

---

**Edit:** I compared your project to mine, and there are clear omissions in yours.

1. When compiling it, the following error is shown, which is nothing like what you wrote in your question:

   > /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool:
   >   -dynamic not specified the following flags are invalid: -ObjC  error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool:
   >   can't locate file for: -lWorklightStaticLibProjectNative error:
   >   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool:
   >   file: -lWorklightStaticLibProjectNative is not an object file (not
   >   allowed in a library)
2. In Build Settings you are missing the `-ObjC` flag in Other Linker Flags
3. Also is missing the following Linked Binary with Libraries: libc++.dylib, UIKit.framework, CoreGraphics.framework.

   In fact, while the folder "frameworks" contains the rest, they are not linked in Linked Binary with Libraries, all of them.
4. I am also pretty sure you did not create a *new project > application > single view application/otherwise*, because your project looks like a completely different kind of project - more like a *library* than *application* type.
5. The project folder structure regarding the Worklight framework is dubious, it's nested, but I suppose that can stay.
6. In Build Phases, the entire section Copy Files is missing.

I have yet to even manage to get yours to work due to the above. My conclusion at this time is that it is not salvageable. Please start over.

Read the training module and follow the instructions. Confirm it looks like demo project (I have also re-uploaded it to contain the missing files).

Comment: Without your project file this isn't a helpful solution.

Comment: It's quite helpful, because it links to a step-by-step guide, but you're right - for the sake of completeness I've edited my answer with  a link to the project.

Comment: Your project makes links to idanadar/Desktop/WorklightAPI/ and idanadar/Desktop/WorklightAPI/Frameworks/- which I obviously don't have, and it's missing build settings http://cl.ly/image/3u331G0u2h05 .  Are you telling me I had to make a separate new project so that I could demonstrate the failure, then you give me back a project you made, and I have to fix this so that I can see the "success"?

Comment: This is an omission on my part that you will Have To change those locations to fit yours. Should be noted that the guide I linked to explicitly mentions to add these frameworks; by providing you a project without these, it wouldn't compile either. Your project seemed incomplete, and you did not write any mention regarding that

Comment: My project was not incomplete - please advise how it was incomplete, and I'll rectify it.

Comment: I will be able to answer this soon as I am replying via mobile. Did you follow the guide? Did you see the project structure af setup? If you choose to argue over little things I can take my time and spend it elsewhere, please stay on course and see if you are able to get it working based on the written in this answer. If it fails still, explain where.

Comment: @amiller, your project is very much incomplete. See my updated answer.